# my activity xml can't see com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to start to develop a map application first time. I get api key from google It's fine but my activity xml couldn't see com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.

Here is my AndroidManifest file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And here is my activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/haritaFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

But couldn't see com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.

I want to share screenshot with you

[image]

Where is the problem ? How can I solve this? It'll be my first map app, and I'm new on Android Studio. Could you help me please?

Comment: Are you including Google Play Services correctly in your project?

Comment: How can I check this? I included it.

Comment: check it in your app's build.gradle file. Do you have something like 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.X.X' in the dependency section ?

Comment: no it haven't and ı added "compile ‘com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+’
        compile ‘com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36′" after that I got an error from here.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

EDIT:

For including google-play services:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: ok, then it seems you didn't include the google play service library correctly. You find an itroducion here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

Add this line to your build.gradle. You probably have missed out on the play-services dependency, which is required to use maps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You need add v4 support library to you gradle file. See [how add](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#buildFileBasics)